# Error running 'sudo pip install -U rosinstall vcstools' on MacOS 10.6.8

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've port install yaml, python selected 2.6, ran easy_install-2.6, and then ran pip below. but it gives me erorr saying yaml.h couldn't be found. I look at the g++ command for it, and it shows a include directory /opt/local/Frameworks/.../include...What does that mean? How do i provide /opt/local/include only?

```
shinkostation:beginner_tutorials sycheng$ sudo pip-2.6 install -U rosinstall
Password:
Downloading/unpacking rosinstall
  Downloading rosinstall-0.6.17.tar.gz (42Kb): 42Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package rosinstall
Downloading/unpacking vcstools (from rosinstall)
  Downloading vcstools-0.1.18.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package vcstools
Downloading/unpacking pyyaml (from rosinstall)
  Downloading PyYAML-3.10.zip (364Kb): 364Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyyaml
Installing collected packages: rosinstall, vcstools, pyyaml
  Found existing installation: rosinstall 0.6.17
    Uninstalling rosinstall:
      Successfully uninstalled rosinstall
  Running setup.py install for rosinstall
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/rosinstall from 644 to 755
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/roslocate from 644 to 755
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/rosws from 644 to 755
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/rosco from 644 to 755
    changing mode of /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/rosco to 755
    changing mode of /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/rosinstall to 755
    changing mode of /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/roslocate to 755
    changing mode of /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/rosws to 755
  Found existing installation: vcstools 0.1.18
    Uninstalling vcstools:
      Successfully uninstalled vcstools
  Running setup.py install for vcstools
  Found existing installation: PyYAML 3.10
    Uninstalling PyYAML:
      Successfully uninstalled PyYAML
  Running setup.py install for pyyaml
    checking if libyaml is compilable
    /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -pipe -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.o
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:2:18: error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c: In function ‘main’:
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:5: error: ‘yaml_parser_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:5: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:5: error: for each function it appears in.)
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘parser’
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:6: error: ‘yaml_emitter_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:6: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘emitter’
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yaml_parser_initialize’
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:8: error: ‘parser’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yaml_parser_delete’
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yaml_emitter_initialize’
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:11: error: ‘emitter’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yaml_emitter_delete’

    libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml
    (if libyaml is installed correctly, you may need to
     specify the option --include-dirs or uncomment and
     modify the parameter include_dirs in setup.cfg)
Successfully installed rosinstall vcstools pyyaml
Cleaning up...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40293/error-running-%27sudo-pip-install--u-rosinstall-vcstools%27-on-macos-10.6.8/) by [shinko](https://answers.ros.org/users/2956/shinko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you need to install libyaml which pyyaml will depend upon.  Or if you pass the --without-libyaml it will probably use a pure python implementation that will likely be slower.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0